# Create child using fork() inside for loop to run execlp() with 2 pipes using dup

Tags: c, linux, for-loop, exec, fork

I am writing a C program which will run Linux commands, like:

> $ cat /etc/passwd | cut -f1 -d: | sort

while waiting for the child to complete, only one child terminates with success. The code hangs displaying "running sort"

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
  int i,fd1[2],fd2[2],status,listpid[3];
  pid_t child;
  pipe(fd1);
  pipe(fd2);

  for(i=0; i< 3; i++)
  {
    printf("\ncreating child\n");
    if((child = fork()) == -1)
    {
      perror("fork");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }
    else if(child == 0)
    {
      if(i == 0)
      {
    close(1); dup(fd1[1]);
    close(fd1[0]);
    close(fd1[1]);
    printf("\nrunning cat /etc/passwd\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    execlp("cat","cat","/etc/passwd", (char *)NULL);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

      }
      else if(i == 1)
      {
    close(0); dup(fd1[0]);
    close(fd1[1]);
    close(fd1[0]);
    close(1); dup(fd2[1]);
    close(fd2[1]);
    close(fd2[0]);
    printf("\nrunning cut -f1 -d:\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    execlp("cut","cut","-f1","-d:", (char *)NULL);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

      }
      else if(i == 2)
      {
    close(0); dup(fd2[0]);
    close(fd2[1]);
    close(fd2[0]);
    close(fd1[0]);
close(fd1[1]);
    printf("\nrunning sort\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    execlp("sort","sort", (char *)NULL);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

      }

    }
    else
    {
      listpid[i]=child;
    }

  }

  close(fd1[0]);
  close(fd1[1]);
  close(fd2[0]);
  close(fd2[1]);

  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
  {
    waitpid(listpid[i], &status, 0);

    if(WIFEXITED(status)) 
    {
      printf("\n[%d] TERMINATED (Status: %d)\n",listpid[i], WEXITSTATUS(status));

    }

  }
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the pipe `fd1` in child 2, otherwise child 1 will hang waiting for more possible input.

As another issue, your `waitpid` loop should have loop condition `i < 3`, not `i < 2`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it "hangs" is because `sort` is waiting for more input. It won't output anything until the input pipes are closed. There *might* be something wrong with your pipes (you should check the return values from `pipe` and `dup`), but I can't see anything.

My guess is that `cut` hasn't exited. Again, the most likely reason is that it's input pipe isn't closed. So, where is it open?

It won't be open in the `cat` process because there's no reason why that wouldn't have exited.

It won't be open in the parent process because you've carefully closed all the descriptors.

It won't be open in the `cut` process because you close the write end of fd1.

That leaves the `sort` process itself: *that* still has fd1's descriptors open!

So, `sort` hangs because it's waiting for `cut` to finish, and `cut` hangs because it's waiting for `sort`, even though sort will never write anything to fd1.

You should either close fd1 in the third child, or you should arrange for each pipe to only exist in the children that need them.

That's my theory anyway.